# function returns boolean instead of appropriate

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, boolean

I am creating an instant messaging platform using HTML, PHP, MySQL and CSS.  My function fetch_conversation_messages (on private_message.inc.php).  Here is private_message.inc.php:

```
     <?php

    // Fetches a summary of the conversations.
    function fetch_conversation_summary(){
            $sql = "SELECT
                                    `conversations`.`conversation_id`,
                                    `conversations`.`conversation_subject`,
                                    MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `conversation_last_reply`,
                                    MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `conversation_unread`
                            FROM `conversations`
                            LEFT JOIN `conversations_messages` ON  `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
                            INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
                            WHERE `conversations_members`.`user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                            AND `conversations_members`.`conversation_deleted` = 0
                            GROUP BY `conversations`.`conversation_id`
                            ORDER BY `conversation_last_reply` DESC";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            $conversations = array();

            while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
                    $conversations[] = array(
                            'id'                            => $row['conversation_id'],
                            'subject'                       => $row['conversation_subject'],
                            'last_reply'            => $row['conversation_last_reply'],
                            'unread_messages'       => ($row['conversation_unread'] == 1),
                    );
            }

            return $conversations;
    }

// Fetches all of the messages in the given converstion.
function fetch_conversation_messages($conversation_id){
        $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

        $sql = "SELECT
                                `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
                                `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `message_unread`,
                                `conversations_message`.`message_text`,
                                `users`.`user_name`
                        FROM `conversations_messages`
                        INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
                        INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
                        WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                        AND `conversations_members`.`user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                        ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $messages = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $messages[] = array(
                'date'          => $row['message_date'],
                'unread'        => $row['message_unread'],
                'text'          => $row['message_text'],
                'user_name'     => $row['user_name'],
        );
  echo mysql_num_rows($result);
           var_dump($row);    

}
return print_r($messages);}


    // Sets the last view time to the current time for the given conversation.
    function update_conversation_last_view($conversation_id){
            $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;
            $time = time() + 18000;
            $sql ="UPDATE `conversations_members`
                            SET `conversation_last_view` = {$time}
                            WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                            AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";

            mysql_query($sql);     
    }

     // Creates a new conversation, making the given users a member.
    function create_conversation($user_ids, $subject, $body){
            $subject        = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($subject));
            $body           = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($body));

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `conversations` (`conversation_subject`) VALUES ('{$subject}')");

            $conversation_id = mysql_insert_id();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_messages` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`, `message_date`, `message_text`)
                            VALUES ({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '{$body}')";

            mysql_query($sql);

            $values = array("({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)");

            foreach ($user_ids as $user_id){
                    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

        $values = array("({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 0)");            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_members` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`, `conversation_last_view`, `conversation_deleted`)
                            VALUES " . implode(", ", $values);

                            mysql_query($sql);
    }


    // Checks to see if the given user is a member of the given conversation.

   function validate_conversation_id($conversation_id){
   $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM `conversations_members`
   WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
   AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
   AND `conversation_deleted` = 0";

   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   return(mysql_result($result, 0) == 1);
   }
    // Adds a message to the given conversation.
    function add_conversation_message($conversation_id, $text){
            $conversation_id        = (int)$conversation_id;
            $text                   = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($text));

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `conversations_messages` (`conversation_id`, `user_id`, `message_date`, `message_text`)
                            VALUES ({$conversation_id}, {$_SESSION['user_id']}, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '{$text}')";

            mysql_query($sql);

            mysql_query("UPDATE `conversations_members` SET `conversation_deleted` = 0 where `conversation_id = {$conversation_id}");
    }

// Deletes (or marks as deleted) a given conversation.
function delete_conversation($conversation_id){
            $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `conversation_deleted`
                            FROM `conversations_members`
                            WHERE `user_id` != {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                            AND `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            //if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 && mysql_result($result, 0) == 1){
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations_members` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
                    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `conversations_messages` WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}");
            }else{
                    $sql = "UPDATE `conversations_members`
                                    SET `conversation_deleted` = 1
                                    WHERE `conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                                    AND `user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}";

                    mysql_query($sql);

            }
    }
    ?>
```

The view_conversation.page.inc.php, which includes the functions of private_message.inc.php, is as follows:

```
    <?php



    $errors = array();
    $valid_conversation = (isset($_GET['conversation_id']) && validate_conversation_id($_GET['conversation_id']));
    if ($valid_conversation === false){
            $errors[] = 'Invalid Conversation ID.';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['message'])){
            if (empty($_POST['message'])){
                    $errors[] = 'You must enter a message.';
            }

            if (empty($errors)){
                    add_conversation_message($_GET['conversation_id'], $_POST['message']);
            }
    }

 if (empty($errors) === false){
        foreach ($errors as $error){
            echo $error;
        }
}


    if ($valid_conversation){
            /*if (isset($_POST['message'])){
                    update_conversation_last_view($_GET['conversation_id']);*/
                    $messages = fetch_conversation_messages($_GET['conversation_id']);
                    print_r($messages);
            }else{
                    $messages = array();
                    update_conversation_last_view($_GET['conversation_id']);
            }


    ?>
                <p class="name">Username: <?php echo $message['user_name']; ?></p>
            <p class="text">Date: <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $message['date']); ?></p>
            <p>Message: <?php echo $message['text']; ?></p>
    <a href="index.php?page=inbox">Inbox</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a>

            <form action="" method="post">
                    <p><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="110"></textarea></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Add Message" /></p>
            </form>

            <?php
            var_dump( $messages );
            if($messages){
            foreach ($messages as $message){
            ?>
            <?php if ($message['unread']) echo 'unread'; ?>


    <?php

    }}
    ?>
```

I get the following output:

Array ( ) 1
bool(true) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u406538221/public_html/public_html/gamma/core/pages/view_conversation.page.inc.php on line 52

I am completely new to this forum, databases, PHP and MySQL.

Problems: invalid argument
returns boolean - why?  How do I fix it?

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why you define fetch_conversation_messages function  twice ?

Comment: I changed it but got the same problem

Comment: can you update the above code with the latest you have. It will help use to figure out the problem

Comment: foreach ($messages as $message){ this is the line where you are getting error right ?
or this one foreach ($errors as $error){

Comment: foreach ($messages as $message)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `fetch_conversation_messages` function is returning `print_r($messages)`.  What this is doing is printing the `$messages` variable (this is where the Array()) is coming from, then it's returning `true`.  Then after calling `fetch_conversation_messages` you are doing `print_r($messages)` and since `$messages` is a `boolean`, `print_r` is printing `1`.  Then your `var_dump($messages)` right before the `foreach` on line 52, the `$messages` variable is a `boolean` equal to `true` and this is where the `bool(true)` output comes from. So you are trying to loop through a `boolean` like an array which is giving you the error about the invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`. So what you need to do is just return `$messages` rather than `print_r($messages)` in your `fetch_conversation_messages` function.

**Edit:**

This is what your `fetch_conversation_messages` should look like:

```
function fetch_conversation_messages($conversation_id){
    $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

      $sql = "SELECT
                            `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
                            `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `message_unread`,
                            `conversations_message`.`message_text`,
                            `users`.`user_name`
                    FROM `conversations_messages`
                    INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
                    INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
                    WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                    AND `conversations_members`.`user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                    ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $messages= array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $messages[] = array(
            'date'          => $row['message_date'],
            'unread'        => $row['message_unread'],
            'text'          => $row['message_text'],
            'user_name'     => $row['user_name'],
    );

    echo mysql_num_rows($result);
    var_dump($row);    

    }
    return $messages;
}
```

Comment: I have done what you said to do however i still get bool(true)

Comment: What is the output after you changed this? Does it still output `Array()`?

Comment: Array ( ) 1
Username:

Date: 31/12/1969 19:00:00

Message:

Inbox Logout




bool(true) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u406538221/public_html/public_html/gamma/core/pages/view_conversation.page.inc.php on line 52

Comment: I edited my answer, above is what you should have for your `fetch_conversation_messages` function.

Comment: When I do that, I get this: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u406538221/public_html/public_html/gamma/core/inc/private_message.inc.php on line 52 Array ( )
Username:

Date: 31/12/1969 19:00:00

Message:

Inbox Logout




array(0) { }

Comment: This means that your `sql` call is returning a `boolean` and since this is a `select` statement it should either return a `resource` if the query succeeds or `false` if the query fails.  Try running the sql outside of php and see what that gives you.  Also a side note, you should be using mysqli_* functions not mysql_* functions as the mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: As far as the `sql` goes, I don't see anywhere in the code that initializes a connection to your database so either you didn't post this code (maybe because it's in another file) or you haven't connected to the database.  In the case of the former, you should check to make sure the user you are connecting as has permission to select from this table and in the case of the latter you'll need to write the php code that connects to your database.

Comment: The connection is in another file - how do I check permission

Comment: I can't run the SQL straight off the database because it relies on PHP variables

Comment: If you are still having problems you could try by hard coding values in place of the php variables and running the sql separate from php, also to check permissions there are a few options...if you have mysql workbench you can go to `users and privileges` and check if the user in question has permission to select on your given schema, if not you could just allow select permissions for the whole schema, or you could just use the `grant` statement to grant select permissions for the required tables to the given user.

Comment: Or you can use this to see all permissions for a given user (excluding global permissions) `select * from \`information_schema\`.\`SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES\`;`

Comment: Thanks for your replies; I have sorted it now :)